# Typescript Error: Argument of type 'NodeListOf<HTMLInputElement> | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Iterable<HTMLInputElement> ..."

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In my React/Typescript App, I am accessing an array of inputs in an event listener through using 'e.currentTarget'.  I am using Array.from() to convert the NodeListOf into an array, and made sure to configure my TS.config.json settings of 'es2015'.  However I'm receiving this error.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cfzjy.png)

Oddly, this error doesn't occur in my original directory.  I had duplicated my project folder, deleted node modules, zipped it, and reopened it, and that's when this error occurs.  Not quite sure how else to approach this issue, if anyone has suggestions or solutions, it'd be appreciated.

```
    e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement> | React.KeyboardEvent<Element>,
    letter: string,
    idx: number,
  ) => {
    const fields: HTMLInputElement[] = Array.from(
      e.currentTarget.parentElement?.parentElement?.querySelectorAll('input')
 )

    const length: number = fields.length
    const position: number = fields.indexOf(e.target)
```

Comment: please share reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide much code, but my guess is this is happening because `e.currentTarget.parentElement?.parentElement?.querySelectorAll('input')` could potentially be undefined. `undefined` cannot be used as the argument for `Array.from`, as `undefined is not iterable`.  You need to make sure it exists before you feed it to `Array.from`.  Two possible solutions:

1. Check that the NodeList you're targeting really exists, then assign your variable

```
if (document.querySelector('.maybe')?.parentElement?.querySelectorAll('.doesnt-exist?')) {
  const fields = Array.from(document.querySelector('.maybe')!.parentElement!.querySelectorAll('.doesnt-exist?'))
}
```

2. Assign your potential NodeList to a variable, but default it to `[]`, just in case.  Autocast that variable as an `HTMLInputElement[]`, and then it can be safely used in `Array.from`:

```
const checker = 
  document.querySelector('.maybe')?.parentElement?.querySelectorAll('.doesnt-exist?') ?? [] as HTMLInputElement[]

const fields: Element[] = Array.from(checker)
```

### [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=7&ssc=1&pln=8&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgSwKYBsAmEByIAOSYC8MAggE6kCGAngHRykgC2AFALABQMMaIwAroyRgoNAI58kpKgGVUSYFBClmAchqNqAIyQqAlAH4aOCqSFQAoiiSDhh8ZJlyFS4ihSqaPJBGEBaJAAeCND6ejAA9OEwkgykEDDawBR8EPgaVDBgILCBwVAcujAcxeyRMACMNDAAwgAW8gDWMFC1FLAt+NhoSAAyeTBUIHwqps0mAOZIUAhg4zCmFG4ZudAQADTN9WAwFBAQCOPbg3ykMABuJggUmlYcCHAwzDz8NiL2UrJWzspq6dp6hmMpmElmsZjsEg+TkUpFc7jUXh8UH8QRCekKAG8OFxQJBYIhUBhCCRyNQ6AwWM8BGYxJDHF8YR4-jpdABCIwmMyg17s970+QwuEeRF+FZQUK6XQcAC+JTKACYqsQ9gcjkNTjhsmYrigYF1ev1FDtzpdrlYNpo+LBunBkihYAh2iAYAADADaAF0XRsAFYpB3bJKpKpFUpRYhW3i7dqtWAXUhXG74XY7bYugASABUALI9ACSYBwVu5Zk93tTaE2QhgjpgSW22hgEAocFQGRSSErM1dZEotHoTBdAC4OLjoHX6sAGpJidjuLxqcJaQ5PgKlEytCzAZyQVZXhCV9CXG5hSBvKLUeKwvp9DBPTt4lncwWixY96WPSUx-jkOgIEOYBLYR7yIXsyQHFhgEnadSCldggA)